Flutter Statefulbuilder with Text Widget Changes
I have a counter in my app. I display the counter second like this.
   Text(
      "$_start second",
      style: GoogleFonts.nunitoSans(
      color: Colors.amber,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      fontSize: 20.0.sp),
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
   ),

Also I have function for the counter. It starts after the press the button.
  void startTimer() {
    const oneSec = Duration(seconds: 1);
    _timer = Timer.periodic(
      oneSec,
      (Timer timer) {
        if (_start == 0) {
          setState(() {
            timer.cancel();
            _isButtonDisabled = false;
          });
        } else {
          setState(() {
            _start--;
          });
        }
      },
    );
  }

My problem is I have a Pinput widget to enter the OTP. After startTimer function starts working, every widgets are renewed and reseted. Because of that, I cant enter the OTP. After my researches, I found StatefulBuilder widget. I used this on some Widgets with setState function and it worked. But I dont have setState funcion in Text Widget. startTimer function has. I could not find any usage like this. How can I do that.
All Dart Code
class SignUpVerifyClientNumber extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignUpVerifyClientNumber({super.key, required this.userId});
  @override
  State<SignUpVerifyClientNumber> createState() =>
      _SignUpVerifyClientNumberState();
  final userId;
}

class _SignUpVerifyClientNumberState extends State<SignUpVerifyClientNumber> {
  late int otpCode;
  late Timer _timer;
  int _start = 150;
  late bool _isButtonDisabled;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _isButtonDisabled = false;
    super.initState();
  }

  void startTimer() {
    const oneSec = Duration(seconds: 1);
    _timer = Timer.periodic(
      oneSec,
      (Timer timer) {
        if (_start == 0) {
          setState(() {
            timer.cancel();
            _isButtonDisabled = false;
          });
        } else {
          setState(() {
            _start--;
          });
        }
      },
    );
  }

  void sendOtp() {
    var rng = Random();
    int refCode = rng.nextInt(9000) + 1000;
    var smsContent = "$otpText$refCode";

    sendSMS(smsContent, "111111111");
    _isButtonDisabled = true;
    startTimer();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.light.copyWith(
      statusBarColor: appColor,
    ));

    final pinController = TextEditingController();
    final focusNode = FocusNode();

    return ScreenUtilInit(
        designSize: const Size(360, 690),
        minTextAdapt: true,
        splitScreenMode: true,
        builder: (_, child) {
          return MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            home: SafeArea(
              child: Scaffold(
                resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
                backgroundColor: whiteColor,
                body: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                       
                        Center(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                vertical: 0, horizontal: 35),
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                          
                                Pinput(
                                  controller: pinController,
                                  focusNode: focusNode,
                                  defaultPinTheme: defaultPinTheme,
                                  separatorBuilder: (index) =>
                                      SizedBox(width: 8.w),
                                  validator: (value) {
                                    if (value == otpCode.toString()) {
                                      context.push(
                                          '/signUpRefCode/${widget.userId}');
                                    } else {
                                      return 'Pin is incorrect';
                                    }
                                    return null;
                                  },
                                  hapticFeedbackType:
                                      HapticFeedbackType.lightImpact,
                                  onCompleted: (pin) {
                                    debugPrint('onCompleted: $pin');
                                  },
                                  onChanged: (value) {
                                    debugPrint('onChanged: $value');
                                  },
                                  cursor: Column(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                    children: [
                                      Container(
                                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 9.h),
                                        width: 22.w,
                                        height: 1.h,
                                        color: const Color.fromRGBO(
                                            23, 171, 144, 1),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  focusedPinTheme: defaultPinTheme.copyWith(
                                    decoration:
                                        defaultPinTheme.decoration!.copyWith(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.sp),
                                      border: Border.all(
                                          color: const Color.fromRGBO(
                                              23, 171, 144, 1)),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  submittedPinTheme: defaultPinTheme.copyWith(
                                    decoration:
                                        defaultPinTheme.decoration!.copyWith(
                                      color: lightAppColor,
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.circular(19.sp),
                                      border: Border.all(
                                          color: const Color.fromRGBO(
                                              23, 171, 144, 1)),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  errorPinTheme: defaultPinTheme.copyBorderWith(
                                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.redAccent),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Gap(30.h),
                                Text(
                                  didntReceiveAnyCodeString,
                                  style: GoogleFonts.nunitoSans(
                                      color: Colors.black38,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 12.0.sp),
                                ),
                                Gap(10.h),
                                Text(
                                  "$_start second",
                                  style: GoogleFonts.nunitoSans(
                                      color: Colors.amber,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 20.0.sp),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                ),
                                Gap(10.h),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                                  height: 40.h,
                                  child: ElevatedButton(
                                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                      backgroundColor: firstAppColor,
                                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                        borderRadius:
                                            BorderRadius.circular(10.sp),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    onPressed:
                                        _isButtonDisabled ? null : sendOtp,
                                    child: Text(
                                      resendNewCodeString,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontFamily:
                                              GoogleFonts.openSans().fontFamily,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                          fontSize: 13.0.sp),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }

  
  final defaultPinTheme = PinTheme(
    width: 50.w,
    height: 50.h,
    textStyle: const TextStyle(
      fontSize: 22,
      color: Color.fromRGBO(30, 60, 87, 1),
    ),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(19),
      border:
          Border.all(color: const Color.fromRGBO(23, 171, 144, 0.4), width: 4),
    ),
  );
}



That's because you setState() of the entire screen, ex: once you opened the keyboard it get dismissed because a new state is pushed, manage that state of that changing text only not the entire screen.

This question is similar to: Flutter FutureBuilder keeps Firing and rebuilding. It Generates a New Random Number on Every Rebuild - How can I Prevent This?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It is not similar dude. Your link is best practice of using FutureBuilder widget. I mention about in the question about StatefulBuilder . In your link, I can fix the question with StatefulBuilder widget. if I wrap FloatingActionButton with StatefulBuilder widget "StatefulBuilder( builder: (ctx, setState) =>" , problem will be fixed actually. Of course best solutionis your answer because of the future. My scenario is after the pressing button. Every _start variable change, PinButton is renewed. I added all codes. Thank you your answer.
